# Showing truncated text on hover using CSS ellipsis overlaps text below it

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a `name` tag in the sidebar which should display single line and truncate if long text follow by triple dots (lorem ipsum...) and should show full text on hover.

I am able to achieve this using css but my problem is when full text is displayed it overlaps the text below it. (Images attached)

HTML

```
<p class="name">
    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p>
```

CSS

```
.name{
    color: #0079c1;
    height: 2em; 
    line-height: 1em; 
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.name:hover{
    overflow: visible; 
    white-space: normal; 
}
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y25okb8L/)

Text overlapping on hover. Expected behaviour is it should push the content below it.
[image]

Comment: Please create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @AMACB https://jsfiddle.net/y25okb8L/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can just add `height:auto` to the `hover` state and it'll work just fine:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6nystnkd/2/)

```css
.name{
    width:120px;
    color: #0079c1;
    height: 2em; 
    line-height: 1em; 
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.name:hover{
    overflow: visible; 
    white-space: normal;
    height:auto;  /* just added this line */
}
```

```html
<p class="name">
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ipsum lorem ipsum
</p>
<span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem voluptate deserunt consequatur velit, alias ullam fuga aspernatur, ut doloremque eos fugiat quo a accusamus minus distinctio quasi, recusandae excepturi molestiae.
</span>
```

Answer (score 30):

Facing similar problem with some long email addresses in a form I created this solution where the full content is displayed on hover in a tooltip-style pseudo element.

```css
body{
  background:#eee;
}
.box{
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  border:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width:10rem;
  margin:2rem auto;
  padding:2rem;
}
.ellipsis {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:.5rem 1rem;
}
.ellipsis:focus, .ellipsis:hover {
  color:transparent;
}
.ellipsis:focus:after,.ellipsis:hover:after{
    content:attr(data-text);
    overflow: visible;
    text-overflow: inherit;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left:auto;
    top:auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 20rem;
    border: 1px solid #eaebec;
    padding: 0 .5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.28);
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display:block;
    color:black;
    margin-top:-1.25rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class='ellipsis' data-text='f6cd8edc-60c2-11e7-9919-ef706e78474f'>f6cd8edc-60c2-11e7-9919-ef706e78474f</p>      
  <p class='ellipsis' data-text='Mauris ac eros odio. Etiam imperdiet vitae dolor eu feugiat. Pellentesque at ante dignissim, tincidunt ipsum quis, rutrum ante. Donec ac lorem nisl. Cras fringilla ex ut rutrum imperdiet. Fusce accumsan id est vel lacinia. Cras nec ligula eu velit mattis mollis. Nunc venenatis neque nibh, id dapibus orci aliquet id. Ut dictum mollis eros sed imperdiet. Phasellus quis enim nec felis sagittis varius. Ut et rutrum quam. Morbi id interdum felis. Mauris id dignissim odio.'>Mauris ac eros odio. Etiam imperdiet vitae dolor eu feugiat. Pellentesque at ante dignissim, tincidunt ipsum quis, rutrum ante. Donec ac lorem nisl. Cras fringilla ex ut rutrum imperdiet. Fusce accumsan id est vel lacinia. Cras nec ligula eu velit mattis mollis. Nunc venenatis neque nibh, id dapibus orci aliquet id. Ut dictum mollis eros sed imperdiet. Phasellus quis enim nec felis sagittis varius. Ut et rutrum quam. Morbi id interdum felis. Mauris id dignissim odio.</p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/natalitique/pen/gRdmre

Requires using data attribute with the full content.

Comment: Nice. Any way to not need the duplicate data-text? Seems redundant... can something like innerHtml be used?

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't seem to allow the user to highlight full text for copy and paste.  @Mi-Creativity answer does provide that functionality.

Answer (score 7):

This code would work and also thanks to the `title` HTML prop the text will be shown on-hover by default

```css
.truncated {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  /* Optional: set a fixed max-width or width to the element if needed */
  max-width: 200px; /* max-width: 100%; also works */
}
```

```html
<div class="truncated" title="This is a long text that will be truncated, but showed on hover">
  This is a long text that will be truncated, but shown on hover
</div>
```