# HTML table cut off long text and show full text on hover/click

Tags: html, css, html-table

First, I know there are a few topics about this out there, but nothing worked for me. I tried the following:

-[Showing truncated text on hover using CSS ellipsis overlaps text below it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833815/showing-truncated-text-on-hover-using-css-ellipsis-overlaps-text-below-it/44968075)

-[Clip long text inside HTML table cells, show entire content on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669939/clip-long-text-inside-html-table-cells-show-entire-content-on-hover)

-And a few solutions I figured out myself.

But none of them worked, so here I am.

I am trying to make a HTML/CSS table, which can contain long text, but it's cut off when the text is longer than the cell is width. I have set the width in my code. But, when you hover over/click on the text (doesn't matter what), the text should be shown full and the table line can also get higher for this.

**My code: JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/bcuhtvdm/**

index.php: (relevant code)

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="t1">Lorem</th>
                <th class="t2">ipsum</th>
                <th class="t3">Lorem</th>
                <th class="t4">ipsum</th>
                <th class="t5">Lorem</th>
                <th class="t6">ipsum</th>
                <th class="t7">Lorem</th>
                <th class="t8">ipsum</th>
                <th class="t9edit"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sedum</td>
                <td>sadipscing elitr</td>
                <td>clita kasd</td>
                <td>clita kasd</td>
                <td>diam voluptuabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</td>
                <td>sed diam</td>
                <td>sanctus est</td>
                <td>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg"></i></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sedum</td>
                <td>sadipscing elitr</td>
                <td>clita kasd</td>
                <td>clita kasd</td>
                <td>diam voluptua</td>
                <td>sed diam</td>
                <td>sanctus est</td>
                <td>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg"></i></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

main.css: (relevant code)

```
table {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td, table th {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: pointer;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
table tr:hover {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  height: auto;
}
table .t1 {
  width: 10%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table .t1:hover {
  width: 10%;
}
table .t2 {
  width: 20%;
}
table .t2:hover {
  width: 20%;
}
table .t3 {
  width: 10%;
}
table .t4 {
  width: 10%;
}
table .t4 {
  width: 11%;
}
table .t5 {
  width: 8%;
}
table .t6 {
  width: 9%;
}
table .t7 {
  width: 11%;
}
table .t8 {
  width: 15%;
}
```

How my page looks at the moment: (relevant part)

[image]

I hope you understand my problem and someone can help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you add this code snippet and tell me if it's working?

```css
tr > td:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: unset;
}
```

Comment: yes, it is!! Thank you! But now it only activates itself when I hover over the cell, but I would like it to activate when I hover over the row. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course, just change the order of the selector: "tr:hover > td"

Comment: perfect, thank you! Could you try to explain it a bit, because I also want to understand the code I write, and I've really no clue what your codes does.

Comment: I will try:
overflow: visible tells the browser to show the element even if it leaves its bounds. So the full text will be shown.
white-space: unset will reset your nowrap. So the text will break if it has no space anymore

Comment: If you hover a tr-tag - the td child elements of this tr will change to { and then your changes }

Answer (score 4):

Displaying long text in tooltip on hover

```
   <style>
    .longTextCss {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow:ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width:1px;
    }
    abbr[title] {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
    
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Long Text</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="longTextCss"><abbr title="Very long text to display">Very long text to display</abbr></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: @Jason Aller - Point well taken. Have added a line description on the approach. And the code is simple and self explanatory. Please let me know if you feel it can be more improvised. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I've exchanged the table .th:hover with table .td:hover. It seems to work.

```
table td:hover {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Can't believe it was so simple. But isn't it possible to activate it when I hover over the row and not only over the cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use text-overflow property

```
table tr:hover td {
    text-overflow: initial;
    white-space: normal;
}
```